# Using Canon Connect for T6i Camera and multiple smartphones

Tags: canon, dslr, canon-700d

I recently bought a Canon EOS Rebel T6i for my wife. It has built-in WiFi so we can connect with our smartphones. I was able to successfully connect my iPhone (both using a Camera Access Point and in Infrastructure mode) and it worked fine. However, when I disconnect my phone and try to connect my wife's iPhone it doesn't work. She is able to log in to the Camera Access Point wifi signal, but then when she opens the Canon Connect app it is not able to make the connection to see that there is a camera to connect to (even though it is on the Camera's wifi network).

Any tips on what might be causing this? When I erased the settings and set up my wife's phone first I was then unable to connect my phone. Is there a single phone limit on each of the connection profiles? I looked and haven't been able to find anything on that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have the Canon 70D which also has the WiFi built-in.  It looks like when you connect a device, some ID for the device,  likely the MAC address is stored, so one Setting = One Device.  However, on the 70D, I can create three settings, so I have: Home-Tablet, which uses my home WiFi, and Away-Tablet and Away-Phone which is using the camera as the access point.   This way, I only need to choose the config I want, and Open Canon Connect on the device.

Comment: How do you create three settings? I'm having the same problem with my 70D. My phone connected fine, but my boyfriends phone doesn't connect.